# Customized data entry fields in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the process of developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application where one of the requirement is to allow the administrator of the application to add additional data capture fields in the screens. What would be the best approach to address this?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches.
First we have to note, that the `Model` itsself should be strongly typed. That leaves you with the option to put your dynamic data into the `Viewbag`. Therefor you should put your second model, or dynamic model, which is not type of your first trongly typed model, into the ViewBag in your Controller action.

The second option is putting your additional datafields, which the administrator can add to the view or hide in the view into your strongly typed `ViewModel`, and just let the administrator tinker with the visibility of the fields.

In addition to that, you could generate two views for 1 action, one which the basic datafields and one with the full set.

Kind regards